# Sending a long string to the web service c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a long Xml file and I did convert it to string so that I can send it to the web service but it is taking to long to process when i send the string, 
the string length in total is 1713117 and the the Xml file it self is 1.31 MB. is taking 1 minute to process.
any Idea of what i can do to make it a bit faster? I' m using ASP.Net c#

Comment: How can we possibly know? what's the server and client hardware? what about the network? anyway, it's too localized.

Comment: the network is  fast and the server as  well client also is a bit faster.

Comment: You talk here for client side compress and server side uncompress ? Do you know that you can upload it with gzip at once ?

Comment: I have no Idea of how this gzip stuff work..can you give me a simple example if you can plz

Comment: heres a working example of gzip upload: http://netpl.blogspot.gr/2009/07/aspnet-webservices-two-way-response-and.html

Answer (score -1):

Use zip methods, gzip, icsharpcode. Zip before and unzip then.